# find and remove any line has this format from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have text files that contain several lines with different formats. I need to delete any line that has only numbers in this format (number.). example, I want to delete only these lines (01.,19,31.,20.). I can't use numbers or positions because numbers and positions differ from file to another

```
0.01        0.01        
80.            1
01. 
19. 
31. 
20. 
51. t4           0.
24. t3           0.
06. t2           0.
01. t1           0.
```

I am trying this,

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != re.match('[0-100].', line):
            f.write(line)
```

The ouput i am looking for

```
0.01        0.01        
80.            1
51. t4           0.
24. t3           0.
06. t2           0.
01. t1           0.
```

Comment: In your regex, `[0-100]` will match only one character: `'0'` or `'1'`. The dot (`.`) will match _any_ one character except the newline. Is this what you intended to write?

Comment: Regex is a great tool but a little challenging to master. It may be more intuitive and simple to get the results you need in another way. Perhaps “if len(line.strip(“\”) >4: ? Or, it looks like your data maybe tab separated, you could check for a tab character: if “\t” in line:

Comment: @ForceBru No, I want to match any line that has only any number between( 01.) to (100.). Also, as you can see above, there is nothing else written after these numbers, unlike the other lines.

Comment: @MAAHE, here are some regex tutorials: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html https://regexone.com

Comment: @Ethan It's tab-separated. Thanks for your idea, I am checking it, it will probably give me what I am looking for. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, there is a problem with the regexp.
In your case, you'll want a condition like this one:

```
if not re.match('^[0-9]{1,3}\.$', line.strip()):
```

The match will be from 0. to 999., if you really want to restrict up to 100. and with always a leading 0, so you can do somthing like this:

```
if not re.match('^(?:[0-9]{2}|100)\.$', line.strip()):
```

You can test your regexp with websites like this one: https://regex101.com/ (don't forget to select Python on the left side)